# numpy's tostring() returning unfamiliar characters

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, wav, tostring

In the process of tweaking scipy's wavfile reader to read only chunks of data at once, I'm encountering a few problems with numpy's tostring() method. Using the default reader to extract the signal and convert to bytes works fine. However, once I use numpy's fromstring() to read a set amount of data (length 512000), tostring() no longer works. Printing either results in a blank line or the terminal asking me if I want to install a dozen new fonts. I use the dtype of the data when extracting, like

`signal = np.fromstring(fid.read(512000), dtype=dtype)`
`print(signal.tostring())`

This usually yields a blank line. If I try to force a dtype, then it'll spit out random characters that don't exist. Using scipy.io.wavfile to read the file, then take a 512000 length segment of it will still convert correctly with tostring(), so I know it isn't a length or a type error. Are there common errors of this type occurring with the tostring() method? How do I fix them?

Comment: What do you mean by, "Using the default reader to extract the signal and convert to bytes works fine"?  Do you mean you can read the wav file using `scipy.io.wavfile.read()` and print it using `tostring()`?  How do you open `fid`?  I suspect that this has to do with the encoding you choose to use when opening `fid`, which `scipy.io.wavfile.read()` takes care of for you.

Comment: @PaSTE I get exactly the same data from scipy.io.wavfile.read() and my code - same length, same type, same values. However, the tostring() method will _only_ work on the data from wavfile.read(). The fid is opened with 'rb', as is the fid in scipy.io.wavfile.read().

Comment: `tostring` docs: `Construct Python bytes containing the raw data bytes in the array.`  In other words, `tostring` is the raw data in the form of byte string.  It's not meant to be 'printed' or displayed.  Have to tried `fromstring` on the result of `tostring`?

Comment: Welcome to the site: you may want to read [help/on-topic], [ask] and [mcve], and re-word your question accordingly.